# Can you return some or all of multiple values as pointers from a function?

Tags: pointers, go

Working with Go I was getting various errors trying to return a string as pointer while returning another value as well. Something like this (pls. excuse for this not being running code, I just wrote it to give a sense of what I want to do since I don't know how to exactly make it work):

```
func A (s string) *string, int {

  // Stuff
  return &a, b
}
*c, d := A("Hi there.")
```

When I try various combinations to say, return the string (var. `a`) as a pointer I get various errors. It's easy and there's dozens of examples with a single variable returned but I'm not sure if it's possible with multiple return values.

Sorry if this seems like a very basic question, I'm still wrapping my mind around Go.

Comment: "various errors" isn't very useful. What _specific_ error do you get, and with what _specific_ code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return multiple variables from a function:

```
func A (s string) (string, int) {
  a := "hello world"
  b := 99

  return a, b
}

c, d := A("Hi there.")
```

One thing I would like to point out is that in Go, strings aren't pointers. In languages like C, you get used to thinking about a `string` as a `char*`, however in Go, a `string` is treated as a primitive much like you would an `int`.

This seems to trip people from time to time, however it is actually quite nice as you don't have to worry about pointers with strings.

If you find yourself in a situation where you want to return a `nil` string (which you can't do because it's not a pointer), then you would return an empty string (`""`).

**Pointers**: If you really want to do pointers...

```
func A (s string) (*string, int) {
  a := "hello world"
  b := 99

  // NOTE: you have to have a variable hold the string.
  // return a, &"hello world" // <- Invalid
  return a, &b
}

// 'd' is of type *string
c, d := A("Hi there.")

var sPtr *string = d
var s string = *d // Use the * to dereference the pointer
```

Comment: Hm, interesting about the strings but I would like to look at this more generically. Let's just for the sake of argument take the integer b and suppose I wanted to pass/return it by pointer (pointless most probably from an efficiency point of view but this is just an exercise) in this two variable return. Would I just put an asterisk after the "int" and the "d" and an ampersand after the b? This was the type of thing that worked with one return variable but was failing me on two return variables but maybe that had something to do with the type of variable at the time.

Answer (score 2):

as said [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) in golang spec, you are wrong in [this](https://golang.org/ref/spec#ParameterList) part so:

```
func A (s string) (*string, int) {
    //stuff
}
```

is the compilable code

Comment: i.e. If you're only returning one variable, it does not need to be inside parentheses (but can be). If you're returning 2 or more then they do.

Comment: yeah, `Result = Parameters | Type .` is what you meant, the second part of or

Answer (score 0):

@poy: I took your code and put in the playground and managed to get it working. I'm not sure what the issue was with why it wasn't working for me but there was probably something else going on. Anyway, with a little massaging this did work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func A (s *string) (*string, int) {
  b := 99

  return s, b
}

func main() {
    r := "Hi there."
    var s *string = &r

    c, d := A(s)
    fmt.Println(*c, d)
}
```